# Hadoop archive file not deleting source files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a source folder which has large number of small files. I want to wrap all the files into single file or container in Hadoop Encryption Zone.

```
hadoop archive -archiveName test.har -p /user/source /user/outputdir
```

The above command will create a .har file in outputdir. But the files in source folder still present.

Is there a way where I can remove all the small files present in source folder and create one archive file. If so, how to unarchive and get back the source files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though archive file is created, the source files still exist. The only solution is to delete the files from hadoop encryption zone.

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash /user/source/*.*
```

Regarding unarchiving:

```
hdfs dfs -cp /user/outputdir/test.har /user/new_destination
```